# CRM2011 Plugin tool not allowing update of existing DLL

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dllregistration

I am currently having a problem where when I try to update an existing DLL, if I update it with the location of Database then I have the following error being returned:

**Error Code:** 2147204725

**Message:**  Plug-in assembly does not contain the required types or assembly content cannot be updated

However if I try to use the disk location option then I have a different error message:

**Error Code:** 2147220906

**Message:** Assembly must be registered in isolation.

Yet I do not understand why this is.  Currently I have tried the following:

- Making sure I am a Deployment Manager (I am not deploying to a Sandbox, as I am trying to update the existing one that is on the server.)
- A colleague who is able to update the plugin has sent me the DLL which he has checked works, to ensure that it is not the DLL that is the problem
- I have tried using the plugin tool on the colleagues computer, to ensure that the version is not the problem - but it still does not work for me.
- The colleague has tried to use the plugin tool on my machine.  However when they do then they get the same errors as I do (although on their machine it works just fine for them but not myself)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be my problem and why I can't seem to update a plugin on my machine?

Thanks

Comment: Does your CRM account have System administartor or System customizer role assigned?

Comment: Yes I am a system administrator on CRM.

Comment: to register in non-sandboxed you need to be a deployment administrator. When you gain this privilege I imagine the errors will match. the library must contain all the same workflows/plugins under the same namespaces as before and any custom workflow activities must have the same I/O parameters as before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error *2147204725* you are getting, could occur when the class name in your plugin is changed.

Your plugin may be registered the first time with a class named *PluginClassName1*, for example, and then registered (updated) a second time, after the class *PluginClassName1* is changed to *PluginClassName2*. In this case, the plugin type, which is the plugin class implementing `IPlugin`, is not retrieved in the already registered assembly.

Other causes could be changing the original assembly metadata (Culture, PublicKeyToken, Name, Version) or the signature key.

To solve the resulting issue, you should **unregister the assembly** and then **re-register it again** and also **re-add the related steps/images**.

Comment: Perfect !! This was issue in my case !!

Comment: I need to register the same assembly in my solution but it is ending up with the same error. Since you said it could be due to class name change in the plugin, I unregistered all the steps from the assembly before re-registering the assembly. Still it is failing.

Comment: If I unregister the assembly itself and register as a fresh one, it creates another instance of assembly while updating already existed managed solution on production instance.

Comment: @Ali.NET: Unregistering the assembly and then re-registering it again (and re-adding the related steps/images) should solve the error. You could try to reproduce the same scenario on a test environment and then apply the suggested solution to check what will happen exactly and if it will effectively solve the problem.

Comment: @amartine I am sorry, I explained it bit wrong. I need to update the same assembly. So I unregistered all steps, and tried to update the assembly again. That fails with same error. ....... If I unregister the assembly itself and re-register as a fresh one, this creates two assemblies on the instances where we already have older version of our solution installed.

Comment: @amartine Issue resolved. The major/minor version of the assembly were changed by the developer who handed over me the code, that was the reason.